# How to retrieve/display formatted text from MySQL Database?

Tags: php, ckeditor

I have formatted text saved in a MySQL database. When I retrieve the data and attempt to display it on the client end, it shows html tags and will not display as it was formatted. I have fiddled with this every which way and cannot seem to get rid of the html tags or make the text appear as it was originally formatted before being saved to the database.

Comment: Is there a standard function used to display formatted text that has somehow escaped me?

Comment: Is "formatted text" just HTML by any chance? This question seems to miss the code used to store it in the database, a content sample, and the code and context in which it was output afterwards. Making a **guess** based on your previous question, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING is a likely culprit.

Comment: Sounds like you stored it as escaped HTML. Samples are needed. `htmlspecialchars` maybe